# Access denied for AWS CloudFront signed URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have set up the following information:

1. Created an AWS S3 bucket and Uploaded some images into the particular folder
2. Created an AWS CloudFront web distribution:

   - Origin Domain Name: Selected S3 bucket from the list
   - Restrict Bucket Access: Yes
   - Origin Access Identity: Selected existed Identity
   - Grant Read Permissions on Bucket: Yes, Update Bucket Policy

[image]

> `AccessDenied`
>       Access denied

I have got the signed URL from the above process like

image.png?policy=xxxxx@signature=xxx@Key-Pair-Id=XXXXXXX

but I couldn't access the URL

Sample JSON for cloud front policy

```
{
    "Statement": [{
        "Resource": "XXXXXXXXXX.cloudfront.net/standard/f7cecd92-5314-4263-9147-7cca3041e69d.png",
        "Condition": {
            "DateLessThan": {
                "AWS:EpochTime": 1555021200
            },
            "IpAddress": {
                "AWS:SourceIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
            },
            "DateGreaterThan": {
                "AWS:EpochTime": 1554848400
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

Added CloudFront bucket policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
            },
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Have you checked if the private key file is properly converted in order to create signed policy URL?

Comment: Please show the complete error.

Comment: @r123 will check

Comment: That error looks like it might be coming from S3. check your S3 bucket policy to make sure there aren't any explicit denies, that the OAI policy was applied, and optionally add `listBucket` on the bucket arn e.g. `arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name`. If you only have getObject permission for a bucket and try to fetch and object that doesn't exist you will get a 403, but you will get a 404 if you have listBucket permissions.

Comment: @cementblocks In bucket policy has permission to acces ListBucket, GetObject and PutObject

Comment: Add the policy to the question.

Comment: @cementblocks i posted the json which is encoded policy statement

Comment: I mean the bucket policy

Comment: @cementblocks Yes. Added

Comment: Please check out my explanation of how to solve this, at https://stackoverflow.com/a/64988224/1207732 cheers!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the AccessDenied error you're seeing has nothing to do with the steps you have mentioned, the Origin access identity it to allow CloudFront to access S3 using a special user using sigv4, using above steps, you'll see a allow statement added to the bucket policy.

If it's a error from S3, you'll see like 2 request ids, host and request Ids along with Access denied massage.

image.png?policy=xxxxx@signature=xxx@Key-Pair-Id=XXXXXXX
If you're seeing Access denied, the error is with CloudFront signed URL (restricted viewer access).

To see whats wrong with the generated CloudFront signed URL, try to base64 decode the policy value and see the Resource URL/expires etc are correct or not.

Comment: Yes, I tried to decode the policy value the given date/time is not expired and resource URL also correct

Comment: hmm, possible to share a sample decode policy or response headers? I assume you also have the correct keypair-id (CloudFront not general AWS access key)

Comment: @dwayneJohn you say the resource URL is correct, but we have no way to confirm this without seeing an example.  The resource must be the full URL the browser is requesting, including the scheme and exact hostname.  Also the signed URL should not contain `@` as you have shown -- the delimiter is `&`.  These details are not trivial.

Comment: How to store the private key from the CloudFront parameter store?

Comment: You need to download the private key locally to use it in the code, btw, the resource url you mentioned and the url you're accessing doesn't match or it just an example ? Since you're accessing custom policy with CloudFront , try using wildcard to aviod typos.

Comment: @JamesDean I can't able to download instead I can copy the private RSA key from the parameter store and stored in my local machine. Is that correct or any other option to download?

Comment: Thats also correct as long as the key is correctly utilized in the signed url code.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I am facing the exact issue.